# logic based on moustache results in algolia

Tags: javascript, mustache, algolia

If I have a moustache attribute say `{{stockvalue}}` and I would like different classes in the surrounding div based on the value of `{{stockvalue}}`say:

```
<div class="label-success">{{stockvalue}}</div>
```

if over 0 and

```
<div class="label">{{stockvalue}}</div>
```

if 0

EDIT 10-NOV-2016

You have both submitted some great solutions as far as I understand, my problem however is that I am using it together with the Algolia instant search system.

```
function app(opts) {
  var search = instantsearch({
      appId: opts.appId,
      apiKey: opts.apiKey,
      indexName: opts.indexName,
      urlSync: true,
      searchFunction: function(helper) {
          var searchResults = $('.search-results');

          helper.search();
          searchResults.show();
      }
  });

  search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
      container: '#search-input',
      placeholder: 'Hvad søger du efter?'
    })
  );

  search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.hits({
        container: '#hits',
        hitsPerPage: 5,
        templates: {
            item: getTemplate('hit'),
            empty: getTemplate('no-results')
      }
    })
  );

  search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.stats({
      container: '#stats'
    })
  );

  search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.sortBySelector({
      container: '#sort-by',
      autoHideContainer: true,
      indices: [{
        name: opts.indexName, label: 'Relevans'
      }, {
        name: 'price_asc', label: 'Laveste pris'
      }, {
        name: 'price_desc', label: 'Højeste pris'
      }]
    })
  );

  search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.pagination({
      container: '#pagination',
      scrollTo: '#search-input'
    })
  );

  search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.refinementList({
      container: '#category',
      attributeName: 'primary-cat',
      showMore: true,
      showMore: { limit: 30, templates: { active: 'Vis mindre', inactive: 'Vis mere' } },
      sortBy: ['isRefined', 'count:desc', 'name:asc'],
        operator: 'or',
        limit: 10,
      templates: {
        header: getHeader('Kategorier')
      }
    })
  );

/*  search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.refinementList({
      container: '#brand',
      attributeName: 'brand',
      sortBy: ['isRefined', 'count:desc', 'name:asc'],
      limit: 10,
      operator: 'or',
      templates: {
        header: getHeader('Brand')
      }
    })
  );
*/
  search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.rangeSlider({
      container: '#price',
      attributeName: 'price',
      templates: {
          header: getHeader('Pris')
      },
      step: 10,
      max: 5000
    })
  );
```

This javascript extracts the stockvalue data and applies it onto the html, but I see no way to do any logic on the stockvalue variable as it is never present in this javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answers are a very good base to solving your issue, the only thing you're missing is a way to integrate this with instantsearch.js.

Here's how to do it using the `transformData` widget option, that allows you to adjust your hits data to your templating needs before rendering:

```
search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.hits({
      container: '#hits',
      hitsPerPage: 5,
      transformData: {
        item: function(hit) {
          hit.stockValueClass = hit.stockvalue > 0 ? 'label-success' : 'label';
          return hit;
        }
      },
      templates: {
          item: getTemplate('hit'),
          empty: getTemplate('no-results')
    }
  })
);
```

You can then use the `stockValueClass` value inside your template:

```
<div class="{{stockValueClass}}">{{stockvalue}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ternary operators in `MustacheJs` as it is logicless. There are a few options however, either adding a value into the object based on its value and then rendering it as `class="{{className}}"` or similar... Or to use javascript once you have rendered the view, as below....

Option 1... (Remember to wrap variable in mustache object! This is an example of logic!)

**View**

```
<div class="{{class}}">{{stockvalue}}</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
   var class;
   if (stockvalue > 0) {
       class = "label-success";
    } else {
       class = "label";
    }
```

Option 2...

**View**

```
<div id="rendered">{{stockvalue}}</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
if (stockvalue > 0) {
   document.getElementById("rendered").className = "label-success";
} else {
   document.getElementById("rendered").className = "label";
}
```

Comment: Hi, both of these solutions show that I can in javascript work with stockvalue, it doesn't seem entirely obvious to me how I would populate that variable using instantsearch.js(that I forgot to mention I was using)

Comment: I've added some more info about the problem concerning the use of algolia instantsearch in the problem.

Comment: Sorry @MattLuccasPhaureJensen, I am unfamiliar with this framework. The only advice I can give is to determine how to capture the response from agolia and assign it to a value in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

So you have your mustache data object defined like:

```
var mustacheData = {"stockvalue":50}
mustacheData['stockvalue_class'] = function(){ 
    if ( this['stockvalue'] > 0 ) { return "label label-success"; }
    else { return "label"; }
}
```

Then in your HTML template you do this:

```
<div class="{{stockvalue_class}}">{{stockvalue}}</div>
```

Comment: I have elaborated the problem so you can see that I sadly might not be able to use your solution.